# Конветрировать object в byte[]

Tags: c#, list, объекты

Как ковертировать объект типа Route в byte[]

```
 [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    public class AirPoint: GeodesicCoordinate
    {
        public long Type;
    }

 [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    public class GeodesicCoordinate
    {
        public double Lat { get; set; }
        public double Lon { get; set; }
    }

 [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
   class Route
   {
      public double CountAirPoints;
      public List<AirPoint> AirPoints = new List<AirPoint>();
   }
```

пробовал несколькими способами

```
byte[] ObjectToByteArray(object obj)
{
    if(obj == null)
        return null;
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

в итоге метод возвращает массив больший по размеру

```
public static byte[] ObjectToByte<T>(T obj)
 {
   var size = Marshal.SizeOf(obj);
   var bytes = new byte[size];
   var ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
   Marshal.StructureToPtr(obj, ptr, false);
   Marshal.Copy(ptr, bytes, 0, size);
   Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
   return bytes;
 }
```

метод не работает потому как не может получить размер List

```
public byte[] ToByte(Route route)
 {
   List<byte> result = new List<byte>();
   result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(CountAirPoints));
   foreach (var airPoint in route.AirPoints)
     result.AddRange(ObjectToByte(airPoint));
   return result.ToArray();
 }
```

метод работает но при изменении структуры его придется переписывать

Comment: Зачем вы используете `BinaryFormatter.Serialize`, а потом пытаетесь вручную десериализовать? Почему не использовать `BinaryFormatter.Deserialize`?

Comment: Я не пытаюсь десериализировать, мне нужно отправить структуру другому приложению по сети, приложение стороннего производителя и оно хочет получить "Чистый" массив т. е. без лишней информации, если бы я это делал в рамках своих(его) приложений, то соответственно я бы использовал BinaryFormatter.Deserialize

Comment: Тогда вам придется его так же вручную сериализовать. Если хотите что бы метод работал при изменении структуры класса, тогда используйте рефлексию что бы получить все поля класса.